# No results using with xmlnamespace exist

Tags: sql, xml-namespaces, exists

I am new to using WITH XMLNAMESPACES and am having some difficulty producing results using the exist() method. The xml column I am querying is as follows:

```
    <Root>
      <ProductDescription ProductID="1" ProductName="Road Bike">
        <Features>
          <Warranty>1 year parts and labor</Warranty>
          <Maintenance>3 year parts and labor extended maintenance is 
                       available       
          </Maintenance>
        </Features>
      </ProductDescription>
    </Root>
```

I am attempting to return an xml namespace in the result set, working from a modified example from Microsoft. However when I execute the following query I get 0 results. Removing the alias from the WHERE clause however does produce results.

```
    WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('uri' as pd)

    SELECT 

        Trans_ID,
        Bike_Sales.query
        (
            '<ProductDescription Product_ID = "{ sql:column("Trans_ID")}"/>'        
        ) AS  Result                                                                            

    FROM XML_EXAMPLE

    WHERE 

        Bike_Sales.exist        
        (
             '/pd:Root/ProductDescription[(pd:Features)]'
        ) = 1
```

So basically I just want to return rows where the Features element is present. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Since there are no namespaces in the input, your where clause can't match anything. Also, is your uri really 'uri'?

Comment: No, "uri" was just an example. This is the example on the MS web site(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms177400.aspx): 

WITH XMLNAMESPACES 
('http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/ProductModelDescription' as pd)
SELECT ProductModelID, CatalogDescription.query('
    <Product 
        ProductModelID= "{ sql:column("ProductModelID") }" 
        />
') AS Result
FROM Production.ProductModel
WHERE CatalogDescription.exist('
     /pd:ProductDescription[(pd:Specifications)]'
    ) = 1
Go